# Rewrite expression to replace List.Contains with custom method

Tags: c#, expression

In an attempt to broaden my skill set, I'm trying to learn how to rewrite expressions.

**Goal:** Given an expression, I want to replace instances of `List.Contains()` with a call to my own static method `InList`. For example, the following two expressions should be equivalent:

```
Expression<Func<Foo,bool>> expr1 = myRewriter.Rewrite(foo => fooList.Contains(foo));
Expression<Func<Foo,bool>> expr2 = foo => InList(foo, fooList);
```

**My attempt:** I've learned that using a [custom ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx) is the best way to create a new expression based on an existing expression. However, I've been unable to build a new `MethodCallExpression` that actually calls my method. Here's what I've tried:

```
public class InListRewriter<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static bool InList(T target, List<T> source)
    {
        // this is my target method
        return true;
    }

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Rewrite(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return Visit(expression) as Expression<Func<T,bool>>;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        // Only rewrite List.Contains()
        if (!node.Method.Name.Equals("Contains", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

        // Extract parameters from original expression
        var sourceList = node.Object;                   // The list being searched
        var target = node.Method.GetParameters()[0];    // The thing being searched for

        // Create new expression
        var type = typeof (InListRewriter<T>);
        var methodName = "InList";
        var typeArguments = new Type[] { };
        var arguments = new[] { Expression.Parameter(target.ParameterType, target.Name), sourceList };
        var newExpression = Expression.Call(type, methodName, typeArguments, arguments);

        return newExpression;
    }
}
```

However, when I call this via `new InListRewriter<Foo>().Rewrite(foo => fooList.Contains(foo))`, I get an `InvalidOperationException` during `Expression.Call`:

> No method 'InList' on type 'MyNamespace.InListRewriter`1[MyNamespace.Foo]' is compatible with the supplied arguments.

I even tried making a new InList with an extremely generic signature:

```
public static bool InList(params object[] things) {...}
```

But still received the same error. What am I doing wrong? Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: The code looks ok. Look at the types that the expression you are passing in as arguments have. Do they match (Foo, List<Foo>)?

Comment: @usr After implementing Daniel's answer and discovering I had a second problem, it turned out that my second problem was that I was accidentally referencing `foo.SomeParam` instead of `foo`, hence the type mismatch and the error I was getting. So you were right as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has one big problem: The arguments it passes are incorrect, specifically the first one.

Instead of `Expression.Parameter(target.ParameterType, target.Name)` you need to use the actual argument: `node.Arguments[0]`.

Furthermore, I suggest you use a different overload of `Expression.Call`: The overload that takes a `MethodInfo`.

The final code would look like so:

```
protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
{
    // Only rewrite List.Contains()
    if (!node.Method.Name.Equals("Contains",
                                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

    // Extract parameters from original expression
    var sourceList = node.Object;      // The list being searched
    var target = node.Arguments[0];    // The thing being searched for
    var newMethod = GetType().GetMethod("InList",
                                        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    // Create new expression
    var newExpression = Expression.Call(newMethod, target, sourceList);

    return newExpression;
}
```

Comment: True, but the `Expression.Call` call should still go through because the types match.

Comment: @usr: I don't think that the exception the OP got is from the code he showed. When I executed his code, I got a completely different one, that better matches the actual problem with his code: *InvalidOperationException: variable 'item' of type 'UserQuery+Foo' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined*. Fixing the issue with the first argument to the method call expression removed that error and the code worked.

Comment: Correct on all accounts. I changed my visitor to match yours and started receiving a different error. However, pulling my code out into a simpler file allowed it to run correctly, so there's something else wrong with my code outside of my re-writer. I'll figure it out eventually. Regardless, you've definitely answered my question, thank you.